# ionic open links in system browser without changing <a> tag

Tags: ionic3

I have an ionic 3 app, in which i get a script that makes an iframe in my content.
When i click the i frame i want the link to open in system browser.

The problem is that i cannot change the contents of the  tag which is in the iframe - I can reach it with several getElementsByTagName but i cannot change it and do something like:

```
<a href="#" window.open(url)><img src="something" /></a>
```

Is there any way to open the links in system browser?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way I found is using whitelist plugin: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

If you can make the whitelist pattern so that all links inside your iframe are against that pattern then they will open in external browser for iOS.

Unfortunately that doesn't work for Android by default, though if you have access and can add

`<base target="_blank"/>`

to the page inside iframe then it will work for Android as well.